# Django - How to use a database table lookup

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to display some data on a webpage using a foreach loop and django.
I do not seem to understand how to use a lookup table that I have created in my Database.

These are the columns from the DB:

```
budget_audit_table:
-BudgetID
-BudgetTypeID <- Foreign Key
-ObjectAuditID
-CustomerID
-DateOfTransaction
-BudgetObject
-Amount

budget_type:
-BudgetTypeID
-BudgetType
```

As you can probably assume in the model.py, the BudgetTypeID is a foreign key.
In the budget_type table I currently have 2 rows:
- Expense: ID 1
- Income: ID 2

Now the problem I'm having is I have searched for a few days now trying to understand Django's API more and I'm struggling to understand how do I for each row that is displayed from the budget_audit_table, how do I instead of displaying the BudgetTypeID (eg 1), it displays the BudgetType (eg Expense)?

Here is my view & template

view.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from models import BudgetAuditTable
from models import BudgetType

@login_required
def index(request):
    budgetauditlist = BudgetAuditTable.objects.order_by('-budgetid')
    template = loader.get_template('budget/budget.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'budgetauditlist': budgetauditlist,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Template

```
{% for budgetauditobject in budgetauditlist %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgetid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.objectauditid }}{{ budgetauditobject.customerid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.amount }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now perhaps you're wondering why I don't use the "Choices" django offers. Because I'm a very database driven person who believes the DB should handle as much as possible and leaving the python as the ask and receive part.

EDIT

models.py

```
class BudgetAuditTable(models.Model):
    budgetid = models.IntegerField(db_column='BudgetID', primary_key=True)
    budgettypeid = models.ForeignKey('BudgetType', db_column='BudgetTypeID', blank=True, null=True)
    objectauditid = models.IntegerField(db_column='ObjectAuditID', blank=True, null=True)
    customerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='CustomerID', blank=True, null=True)
    dateoftransaction = models.DateField(db_column='DateOfTransaction', blank=True, null=True)
    budgetobject = models.CharField(db_column='BudgetObject', max_length=255, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(db_column='Amount', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'budget_audit_table'

class BudgetType(models.Model):
    budgettypeid = models.IntegerField(db_column='BudgetTypeID', primary_key=True)
    budgettype = models.CharField(db_column='BudgetType', max_length=25, blank=True)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'budget_type'
```

Comment: So can anyone help me? I'm still having trouble

Comment: I'm looking for lookup table implementation as well. :/

Answer (score 1):

You should really have shown your models. If `budgettypeid` is the Django ForeignKey field, then  `budgetauditobject.budgettypeid` would give you the actual BudgetType object, and then you can access its fields with the normal dot notation.

Comment: I have tried again, but it still only returns a 1 for the result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid }}</td>
```

have you tried:

```
<td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}</td>
```

?